# Grok Pattern for Non Printable Characters

Tags: logstash-grok, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We have files delimited with control character (backspace);

```
1234<0x008>john<0x08>smith
4321<0x008>steve<0x008>idle
```

Whatever grok pattern I tried not really parsing the file sitting in s3 and also the grok debuggers not really helping with nonprintable characters
I have this and obviously it is wrong;

```
%{DATA:ID}0x08%{DATA:FIRST_NM}0x08%{DATA:LastName}\n
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly

```
%{DATA:ID}[\x00\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]%{FIRST_NM}[\x00\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]%{DATA:LastName}$
```